# How to set the color of individual pixels with moviepy

Tags: python-3.x, pixel, moviepy

I want to create a custom video where each pixel represents the result of a mathematical function. I've tried `clip.get_frame(f)[y][x] = (r, g, b)` but that doesn't work, the video stays unmodified.

How could I go about doing this? Also, are there better plugins for doing this kind of thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `VideoClip` class with a `make_frame` function (a function
`t -> frame at time t` where `frame` is a `w*h*3` RGB array representing the pixels). [[Docs]](https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/ref/VideoClip)

Here's an example `make_frame` function using `numpy`; it generates a random array of pixels for each `t`.

```
from moviepy.editor import *
import numpy as np

def make_frame(t):
    w, h = 320, 180  # Width an height.
    return np.random.random_integers(0, 255, (h,w,3))

clip = VideoClip(make_frame, duration=2)
clip.write_gif('random.gif', fps=15)
```

As a result, we get:

[image: Random Pixels Animation]